# Is there only one instance of a static variable per process?

Tags: c#, .net, oop, assemblies, static-members

If I have the following class:

```
public class MyClass { public static int MyStaticInt = 0; }
```

If in the one solution I refer to `MyNameSpace.MyClass.MyStaticInt` in two different assemblies, am I referring to the same variable?

Comment: if it's the same program that runs.

Comment: shouldn't the class be static as well and named MyStaticClass?

Answer (score 6):

Static state is scoped per [`AppDomain`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.aspx) by default and can be configured to be by thread if you use the [`ThreadStatic`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threadstaticattribute.aspx) attribute.

This means that your assumption is valid if the assemblies are running in the same process and the process has only one application domain.

Answer (score 5):

`static` can mean several things depending on context.

- By default, you get one instance of the value per `AppDomain`.
- If decorated with the `ThreadStatic` attribute, you get one instance of the value per thread.
- If contained within a generic class, you get one instance of the value per concrete type.

For your example code, the first condition appears to be the case. In all cases, the specific assembly that the data is defined in does not make any difference.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, because it also covers the generic case (not asked but google quickly leads here).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is only one instance per process per class.

A small caveat to this is when you have generic classes where you have one instance of the variable per instance of the generic class.  I.e. you would have one instance for MyGenericClass and one for MyGenericClass.

**EDIT**

In fact there is one instance per AppDomain, so you can create multiple copies by creating mulitple copies of the AppDomain yourself.

Answer (score 0):

**No**, MyClass.MystaticInt is local to class MyClass only.

Answer (score 0):

I've tested the static instance in a "*custom*" assembly, which is loaded from two locations: the *main* program (3rd party) and my "*home-made*" plugin that is loaded also by the *main* program. I've checked the AppDomain - it is exactly the same when the "*custom*" assembly is loaded from both places, alas the static instance of an object in a "*custom*" assembly is not the same. Therefore I have to conclude that static instance has the aforementioned single value per AppDomain per loaded assembly, if the assembly is loaded again, then it will not be the same.

Answer (score 0):

class variable are static.
there is only one occurance of a class variable per jvm per classloader.